# High end networking questions?

Tags: discussion

I just posted this on serverfault.com and realized it didn't really have that much to do with "Systems Administration".

Thoughts? Maybe its too small a category to have its own site, but "sys admins" typically don't train all that much on advanced networking topics.  (Or am I biased?)

[When would you use MPLS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/60832/when-would-you-use-mpls)

Answer (score 12):

I think you might be taking "sys admin" too literally. I think your question fits perfectly for SF.

Answer (score 6):

From SF FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Server Fault is for system administrators and IT professionals, people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity. If you are in charge of ...
>
> - servers
> - **networks**
> - many desktop PCs (other than your own)

Comment: And in case it isn't obvious enough - A network admin IS a system admin.

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to me. Although you could do a bit of work making that question a little more terse and to the point.

Comment: :p

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are a sys admin asking other sys admin's about networking questions you'll get an answer that's on your level.  I think if you are a systems-network hybred admin and have or are working on your CCNP and are designing an MPLS addition to your network, there's not a lot of that expertise here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect question for SF.  Systems administration takes on all aspects of managing a network and all the services/devices hardware/software that run on it.

Answer (score 0):

ISPs are businesses too, and they have professional systems admins, who have very advanced networking requirements.  It may be the case that a specialist SE site would be more appropriate for those users, but their questions are perfectly OK for SF.